# EmguCV System.ArgumentException: 'Unable to decode file'

Tags: c#, emgucv

I am trying to [instantiate an EmguCv Mat](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/3.1.0/document/html/2ec33afb-1d2b-cac1-ea60-0b4775e4574c.htm) using a file path and EmguCVEnum as the parameters.

The code looks like this

```
using (Mat mat = new Mat("Y:\\Desktop\\test.dng", ImreadModes.Unchanged))
```

However it is throwing an error:

> System.ArgumentException: 'Unable to decode file: Y:\Desktop\demTest\ATHS4829.dng'

**Is there a way to create a Mat using a DNG file or its image data?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue by retrieving the bytes stored inside the DNG and putting them into an array. Then creating a `Image<Bgr, ushort>` object using the bytes array. After that i was able to call

```
UMat mat = img.ToUMat();
```

Comment: Could you please provide us how you retrieved the bytes stored in the DNG, please?

Comment: Yes we implemented https://github.com/FSchiltz/RawParser in our project which contains a DNGDecoder class that allows you to extract the bytes

Answer (score 0):

I quote:

> DNG is also considered to be a RAW image file. It is Adobe's
>   proprietary image standard that was created to store image data in a
>   generic, highly-compatible format, unlike RAW files that have specific
>   formats based on manufacturer and camera type.

So I doubt that EmguCV/OpenCV can read an Adobe proprietary format.

Doug